# php say some results aren't undifined while some are

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a wierd php problem. I get data from mysql with code below

```
SELECT kitap.kit_id, kitap.kit_adi, yazar.yad as yazar,  
        yayinevi.yeviad as yayinevi,kitap.isbn,kitap.basim_yili, 
        kitap.baski_no,kitap.dil,kitap.cilt,kitap.sayfa, 
        kitap.kategori,kitap.durum
FROM kitap 
    INNER JOIN kitapyayinevi ON kitap.kit_id = kitapyayinevi.kit_id 
    INNER JOIN kitapyazar ON kitap.kit_id = kitapyazar.kit_id 
    INNER JOIN yayinevi ON kitapyayinevi.yevi_id = yayinevi.yevi_id 
    INNER JOIN yazar ON kitapyazar.yazar_id = yazar.yazar_id
SQL;

    $stmt = $connection->query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result); //This is for debugging purposes
```

But when I try to print them with code below;

```
<?php foreach ($result as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="hide"><?= $item->kit_id; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->kit_adi; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->yazar; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->yayinevi; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->isbn; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->baski_no; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->basim_yili; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->dil; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->cilt; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->sayfa; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->kategori; ?></td>
```

It gives me the error below. Everything except $item->yazar and $item->yayinevi print out just fine;

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$yazar in C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\KutuphaneYonetim\php\body.php on line 38
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$yayinevi in C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\KutuphaneYonetim\php\body.php on line 39

And var_dump($result) prints out like this;

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { 
                ["kit_id"]=> string(2) "25" 
                ["kit_adi"]=> string(7) "Sınır" 
                ["yazar"]=> string(13) "Beyza Alkoç " 
                ["yayinevi"]=> string(15) "İNDİGO KİTAP" 
                ["isbn"]=> string(10) "6052361580" 
                ["basim_yili"]=> string(4) "2018" 
                ["baski_no"]=> string(1) "4" 
                ["dil"]=> string(8) "TÜRKÇE" 
                ["cilt"]=> string(12) "Karton Kapak" 
                ["sayfa"]=> string(3) "400" 
                ["kategori"]=> string(5) "Roman" 
                ["durum"]=> string(5) "rafta" 
                } 
        }
```

What would be the problem? can you guys help me find?

Comment: at a guess, can those fields be null in your database?

Comment: If you format your question and code to be readable, more people will stop to look at it, and it also helps you debug your own code

Comment: @ADyson   no they arent  var_dump ($result)  prints ["yazar"]=> string(13) "Beyza Alkoç " ["yayinevi"]=> string(15) "İNDİGO KİTAP"

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks i'm new but i edited a little bit for better readability

Comment: Try changing `yazar.yad as yazar` in `yazar.yad as yazar2` and `<td><?= $item->yazar2; ?></td>`. You are using the tablename as an alias, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**FETCH_ASSOC** so they are all returned as arrays. You are addressing them as if they were objects so for example use

```
<td><?= $item['yazar']; ?></td>
```

Alternativley change the fetchAll to

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

and leave the code as you originally had it.

Comment: all of them prints out fine except yazar and yayinevi. i tried what you said before posting here but that give me another error.

Comment: @Nihal Please update the question with the new error.

Comment: Now you have changed your question and you are using fetchAll with  **PDO::FETCH_OBJ** which one are you using

Comment: sorry @RiggsFolly I tried assoc mode  may be it was the problem  then left it there but I always use obj mode

Comment: Thanks I changed it to assoc and changed SQL a bit. That worked with single quote's.

Answer (score -2):

try to convert obj to array so if your value obj or value null that it was not given any error and it's to easy to manage array.

add before your loop.

```
<?php $result = json_decode(json_encode($result),true); ?>
```

Comment: You should look at the fetch options. This is a very roundabout way of doing that. `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php